# Searching for a statistics formula

Tags: mathematical-statistics, excel

I have the following problem that I can't wrap my head around. I've tried to exemplify in the attached excel screenshot below.

I have an input, "target a", which is a fixed number that has to be randomly distributed into 6 bins that are labeled with their fixed values of (5,10,15,30,100,1000). This works due to the formula in H8, and I can evenly distribute the number (5050 in this example) to all 6 bins, as verified by the total in I9.

The problem comes when the expected number of randomly generated frequencies in each bin (column I) once multiplied by the actual value of the bin in every row (J), (meaning each 5, 10, 15, 30, 100, 1000) and cumulated for the whole 6 bins should be equal to the other input which is also a fixed value "target b" (1.000.000) in this case.

[image: Excel Screenshot Here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZZ1z.png)

So, the number of expected randomly generated frequencies (Group A) with a max of 5050 (target A) should be distributed in 6 bins and each of the numbers once multiplied with the fixed value of the bins (also their label) and cumulated with the number of bins (6), let's call them Group B, should sum up to another fixed number which is 1.000.000 (target b).

does anyone know a formula that I can apply or how to achieve this??

thanks

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that what you're asking is impossible.

You cannot randomly generate $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^6$ where each $x_i$ is $i.i.d.$ and $x_i ~ U(0,1)$ such that:

$$(5x_1 + 10x_2 + 15x_3 + 30x_4 + 100x_5 + 1000x_6) \frac{5050}{\sum_{i=1}^6 x_i} = 1,000,000$$

That is because you have got an equation that places a constraint on what the values of $x_i$ can be.

As an anaolgy, imagine I asked you to randomly sample two integers between 1 and 10 such that their sum is 10. You can randomly sample 1 of them sure, but then the other one is perfectly determined. You are facing the same problem here.

---

However, we can reframe the problem.

Why don't we try to find $x$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^6 x_i = 1$

And $5x_1+10x_2+15x_3+30x_4+100x_5+1000x_6 = \frac{1,000,000}{5050}$

Solve for $x_5$ by putting Eq. 1 into Eq. 2, then solve Eq. 2 for $x_6$

We have $x_5 = 1 - x_1 - x_2 - x_3 - x_4 - x_6$

And $x_6 = \frac{1}{900}\left[\frac{1,000,000}{5050} -100 + 95x_1 + 90x_2 + 85x_3 + 70x_4 \right]$

Including these as Excel formulas you will need many samples before getting all $x_i$'s to be $\gt1$, but I generated the following numbers that solve your problem for example:

[image]

Here are those formulas: Remember that this will generate negative values of x_6 almost every time, so I don't know if I'd call it a solution. You will need something more advanced (through more thinking or an optimisation tool) to get x_6 always between 0 and 1.

[image]

Comment: This works and it's fantastic. But I'm trying to transform this into a c++ component. and unless I can understand how to apply it in excel, I don't understand how to implement the formulas.  Any related materials, that can help me understand how to include that formula into excel would be greatly appreciated. Anyway thanks for putting up the time for this.

Comment: No worries, added that in Excel now.